# How to convert to JSON

Tags: php, json

I'm having a hard time to parse this PHP to JSON kan someone help me with this how can I convert this PHP into JSON

```
$query = "SELECT SUM(total)  FROM account";
$result = mysql_query($query);

while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result))
{
echo $row['SUM(total)'];
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Try with `json_encode` like

```
$query = "SELECT SUM(total) as total  FROM account";
$result = mysql_query($query);
while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result))
{
    $new_arr[] = $row['total'];
}
echo json_encode($new_arr);
```

Try to avoid using `mysql_*` functions due to they are deprecated.Instead use `mysqli_*` functions or `PDO` statements.

Answer (score 1):

```
$query = "SELECT SUM(total) as t  FROM account";
$result = mysql_query($query);

while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result))
{
    $new_arr[] = $row['t'];
}
echo json_encode($new_arr);
```

Answer (score 0):

use `json_encode()` function in php.

Check the reference [here](http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-encode.php)

```
while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result))
{
    $myArray[] = $row['SUM(total)'];
}
echo json_encode($myArray);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result))
{
    $new_arr[] = array("total"=>$row['SUM(total)']);
}
echo json_encode($new_arr);
```